# Firebase Storage - Link not created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image and a document to the firebase storage and upload the links created from both to the Real-Time DB, everything happening on a button's click.
But in the firebase DB, the links are not uploaded while the other text I upload along with them is there.

Storage upload code:

```
updata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //before uploading both the doc and img..
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Images");
            progressDialog.show();

            final UploadData uploadData=new UploadData();

            if(ImgPathUri!=null){
                StorageReference str=storageReference.child(StoragePath + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(ImgPathUri));

                str.putFile(ImgPathUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                                String ImgLink=uri.toString();
                                                linkimg=ImgLink;
                                                uploadData.setImgURL(linkimg);

                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(addEventActivity.this, "fucked ra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finished=false;
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            }
                        });
            }

            if(DocPathUri!=null){
                StorageReference storageReference1=storageReference.child(StoragePath + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(DocPathUri));

                storageReference1.putFile(DocPathUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                String DocLink=uri.toString();
                                                linkdoc=DocLink;
                                                uploadData.setDocURL(linkdoc);
                                            }
                                        })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("TAG_FOR_FAILURE LOG", "On Failure: The exception", e);
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                finished=false;
                                Toast.makeText(addEventActivity.this, "doc fucked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();


            String info=infoText.getText().toString();
            String event=eventName.getText().toString();

            uploadData.setName(event);
            uploadData.setInfo(info);

            //uploading the event name,info and other file links to the RTDB under the event name
            databaseReference.child(event).setValue(uploadData);

        }
    });

}
```

Where updata is the button, ***UploadData*** is the class for holding those all those values...

After I click the button the image is stored in the Storage while the Database holds nothing but,

```
data {
   name:"given name"
   info:"given info"
}
```

while it has to have included the **ImgLink** and **DocLink**.
Where does it lose track?

Comment: Did you enable Storage in Firebase Console?

Comment: thanks for the reply... Yes I added already

Comment: Okay, does it give any error in logcat?

Comment: No, nothin showed up

Comment: But when i Toast the strings which are holding the links, they show null and null

Comment: You should call setValue after getDownloadUrl.  That's why you see just name and info

Comment: Yeah , but the setValue is indeed after the getDownloadUrl

Comment: No, it does not work as you think. Before setValue runs after getDownloadUrl. You can add breakpoint and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

**Declare this object globally**

```
Uri uri;
```

**Set uri when user fetches the Image from the gallery**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            jimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here sUrl will have downloadURL**

```
private void uploadImage() {
    try {
        final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(  UUID.randomUUID().toString() );

        //uploads the image
        ref.putFile( uri ).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        final Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                        sUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

                    }
                } ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                    }
                } );


            }
        } );
    }catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: Inside .addOnFailureListener() add a log and print Exception object and copy paste log cat to your question

Comment: No signs of failure :(

Comment: Can you update your question code wherever you did the changes?

Comment: Remove file extension "." + getExtension(ImgPathUri)

Answer (score 0):

Each `onSuccess` method is called asynchronously, after the call to the server has completed. Since this takes time, you main code continues, and this means you're writing to the database, before the download URL is available.

It's easiest to see this if you place some log statements in your code:

```
Log.i("STORAGE", "Starting to upload image data");
StorageReference storageReference1=storageReference.child(StoragePath + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(DocPathUri));

storageReference1.putFile(DocPathUri)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.i("STORAGE", "Image data uploaded, getting download URL");

                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("STORAGE", "Got download URL");
                                String DocLink=uri.toString();
                                linkdoc=DocLink;
                                uploadData.setDocURL(linkdoc);
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TAG_FOR_FAILURE LOG", "On Failure: The exception", e);
                    }
                });

            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                finished=false;
                Toast.makeText(addEventActivity.this, "doc fucked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

...

uploadData.setName(event);
uploadData.setInfo(info);

Log.i("STORAGE", "Writing info to database");
databaseReference.child(event).setValue(uploadData);
```

The output of this is:

> Starting to upload image data
>
> Writing info to database
>
> Image data uploaded, getting download URL
>
> Got download URL

This is probably not what you expected, but it is working as intended, and completely explains why the download URL isn't written to the database: by the time you write to the database, the download URL hasn't been loaded yet.

---

The solution to this problem is always the same: any code that requires the download URL, need to be inside the `onSuccess` method that gets called when the download URL is retrieved (or at least needs to be called from there).

So something like:

```
updata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //before uploading both the doc and img..
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Images");
            progressDialog.show();

            final UploadData uploadData=new UploadData();

            if(ImgPathUri!=null){
                StorageReference str=storageReference.child(StoragePath + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(ImgPathUri));

                str.putFile(ImgPathUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                                String ImgLink=uri.toString();
                                                linkimg=ImgLink;
                                                uploadData.setImgURL(linkimg);

                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(addEventActivity.this, "fucked ra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finished=false;
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            }
                        });
            }

            if(DocPathUri!=null){
                StorageReference storageReference1=storageReference.child(StoragePath + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getExtension(DocPathUri));

                storageReference1.putFile(DocPathUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                String DocLink=uri.toString();
                                                linkdoc=DocLink;

                                                uploadData.setDocURL(linkdoc);


                                                progressDialog.dismiss();


                                                String info=infoText.getText().toString();
                                                String event=eventName.getText().toString();

                                                uploadData.setName(event);
                                                uploadData.setInfo(info);

                                                //uploading the event name,info and other file links to the RTDB under the event name
                                                databaseReference.child(event).setValue(uploadData);
                                            }
                                        })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.e("TAG_FOR_FAILURE LOG", "On Failure: The exception", e);
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                finished=false;
                                Toast.makeText(addEventActivity.this, "doc fucked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Hey Akash. Did you get anywhere based on my answer?