# Getting the names of items from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference downloadRef;
StorageReference listRef;
Object Downloads;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    listRef = storage.getInstance().getReference("Project");
    listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for (StorageReference items : listResult.getItems()) {
                arrayList.add(items.getName());
            }
        }
    });

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

So I am new to android, and this is what I tried to get the names of the documents so I can display them with listView. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You aren't doing wrong. Do you have any folders in Firebase Storage?  Maybe your reference is wrong.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir so I added a folder and tried that way, I have also noticed that it never gets into for loop. I have updated the code part.

Comment: If you put a `Log.i("STORAGE", listResult.getItems().size())` statements inside `onSuccess`, what does it print in the logcat output?

Comment: Your code is correct. I think, There is rules problem. Have you authenticated?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I/STORAGE: 2

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I haven't authenticated but I changed the rules from Firebase to `allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
` because it's still in the testing phase. I'm planning to add authentication later on.  The parts of my code used for download files works, so I don't think it's about authentication. Should I still add right now?

Comment: If size of list is 2, it means you have two documents. Have you tried debug mode? You can see the result.

Comment: Hey Kerem. Since the log statement works, your code **is** being called. My guess is that you're new to dealing with asynchronous APIs. If that's the case, I recommend checking out my answer/explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60928823/firebase-storage-link-not-created/60933705#60933705 too

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir is error supposed to be colored red in debugging? if so there is no error

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen alright thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `onSuccess` is getting called, which means you get a list of files from Firebase.

What's most likely happening is that you're processing this list correctly, but then not telling the adapter that you've changed its data. To tell the adapter that its data has changed call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it:

```
listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
        for (StorageReference items : listResult.getItems()) {
            arrayList.add(items.getName());
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

At that point the adapter will repaint the associated views, and your data should show up.

Comment: This solved my problem and my list is visible now, thanks a lot!